# C++ STL list functions segfaulting with empty list

Tags: c++, list, stl

I have a list of pointers as a member of a class.  I instantiate that class, and various functions such as size() and empty() fail with a segfault when the list is empty.  When I add something to the list, they're fine.  I tried to abstract what I'm doing with a test file, and it works perfectly.  This is what I THINK I'm doing when my code fails (though am clearly not):

```
#include <list>
#include <iostream>

class Test {
  int i;
};

int main() {
  std::list<Test*> tlist;

  if (tlist.empty()) {
    std::cout << "List empty";
  } else {
    std::cout << "List not empty";
  }
}
```

I can't really post the entire code listing that's causing the issue, as it's fairly large and over a bunch of files, but will try to paste all the relevant bits straight from code:

Class declaration in player.h:

```
class Player : public ScreenObject {
private:
    std::list<Thing*> inventory;
```

Nothing is done to that list in the constructor.

Where it's failing:

main.cpp:

```
Player pc(iname, w_choice, c_choice, 11, 11, WHITE, '@');
```

....

```
if (pc.addToInv(t)) {
    currentLevel.delObject(id);
}
```

....

player.cpp:

```
int Player::addToInv(Thing& t) {
    if (inventory.size() <= 52) {
        inventory.push_back(&t);
    } else {
        shiplog("Cannot add to inventory, 52 item limit reached",10);
        return 0;
    }
}
```

The error I get when running it with gdb occurs on the call to size(), and ends up here:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0804eda6 in std::_List_const_iterator<Thing*>::operator++ (this=0xbfff9500)
at /usr/include/c++/4.4/bits/stl_list.h:223
223            _M_node = _M_node->_M_next;
```

Any guesses much appreciated!

---

Full backtrace is:

```
(gdb) bt
 0  0x0804e28a in std::_List_const_iterator<Thing*>::operator++ (
    this=0xbfff9500) at /usr/include/c++/4.4/bits/stl_list.h:223
 1  0x0804e64e in std::__distance<std::_List_const_iterator<Thing*> > (
    __first=..., __last=...)
    at /usr/include/c++/4.4/bits/stl_iterator_base_funcs.h:79
 2  0x0804e4d3 in std::distance<std::_List_const_iterator<Thing*> > (
    __first=..., __last=...)
    at /usr/include/c++/4.4/bits/stl_iterator_base_funcs.h:114
 3  0x0804e2e6 in std::list<Thing*, std::allocator<Thing*> >::size (
    this=0xbffff244) at /usr/include/c++/4.4/bits/stl_list.h:805
 4  0x0804df78 in Player::addToInv (this=0xbffff068, t=...) at player.cpp:551
 5  0x0804a873 in main (argc=1, argv=0xbffff494) at main.cpp:182
```

Comment: run it in debugger till crash, check the back trace of stack and examine value of variables.

Comment: Is there any other place in your code where you are modifying inventory?

Comment: Since the size of a `std::list` has to be computed, the list iterates through its entries - that is done with `operator++`. However, i do not understand why this should cause a segfault. Complete backtrace please? Notwithstanding the above, I *guess* its caused because you use pointers in a dangerous way ...

Comment: `this=0xbfff9500` just isn't possible on a 32-bit system, so something has corrupted the data earlier. Writing out-of-range, for example.

Comment: Added complete backtrace to question

Comment: I have checked the entire codebase, and nothing touches that list apart from the push_back() here, and an erase() in a corresponding delFromnInv() call which isn't used; there's just the declaration of the class...

Comment: It seems you messed up the list somehow, possibly you overwritten the stack somewhere?

Comment: Its not what touches the list that will hose it; its what *overwrites* the list *data*. Ultimately something is walking into the list object itself and corrupting it. what that is is anyone's guess. You could try using Valgrind to track it down, I assume the reason for the dynamic `Thing` pointers is for polymorphic derivation, correct? Who owns the inventory object (i.e. where is it declared? is it a member of another object? I see it in Player, but who owns *that*?). What about the pointers held within? where are *they* actually **allocated**?

Comment: This works fine: http://ideone.com/y2MPW8.  So the problem must be in something that you aren't showing us.  Try removing different parts of the Player class (including it inheriting from ScreenObject) until the problem goes away-- then you've at least got something to look at.

Comment: Hey, could you figure out what your problem was? Some tip? I am having exactly the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
int Player::addToInv(Thing& t) {
if (inventory.size() <= 52) {
    inventory.push_back(&t);
} else {
    shiplog("Cannot add to inventory, 52 item limit reached",10);
    return 0;
}
```

}

*Thing* is passed by reference, but then its address is passed to inventory.push_back().  Try just passing 't'.

Comment: The segfault occurs before the push_back().  Also, if I change it as suggested, it won't compile:
    no matching function for call to ‘std::list<Thing*, std::allocator<Thing*> >::push_back(Thing&)’