# gdb and debugging problems with an STL list

Tags: c++, list, stl, gdb, segmentation-fault

I recently asked a question here, and didn't get an answer I could use, unfortunately:

[C++ STL list functions segfaulting with empty list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14899678/c-stl-list-functions-segfaulting-with-empty-list)

I've been trying to use gdb to debug the issue, and I have a question about what something means:

I declare a list as a member of a class like so:

```
std::list<Thing*> inventory;
```

...and then instantiate the class it's in (an object called 'pc').  In gdb, I presume this shows that I have some memory allocated to it?

```
(gdb) p &pc.inventory
$7 = (std::list<Thing*, std::allocator<Thing*> > *) 0xbffff22c
```

Further in, one line before the problem line of the code (in essence, calling 'inventory.size()' causes a segfault), this still holds:

```
(gdb) p &inventory
$8 = (std::list<Thing*, std::allocator<Thing*> > *) 0xbffff22c
```

...however I still get the segfault:

```
(gdb) n
558   if (inventory.size() == 52) {
(gdb) n

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0804e3fe in std::_List_const_iterator<Thing*>::operator++ (this=0xbfff94e0)
at /usr/include/c++/4.4/bits/stl_list.h:223
223     _M_node = _M_node->_M_next;
```

My question is essentialy this:  Surely, if I have an address for the member list, the list exists, and I should be able to use size() on it??  If not, why not?  And how could I further debug?

Thanks all!

Comment: Just because something has a non-null address doesn't mean it's a valid address. C++ doesn't set pointers to null when initialized or invalidated, it just uses what's in the memory at that time. From what you've shown this could very well be the problem. Construct a minimal test case that reproduces the problem and we may be able to help.

Comment: Thanks, Dukeling, I did that, and have found the root of the issue.  Still don't know how to fix it though!  Here it is:
 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15133520/array-setup-in-constructor-means-failure-later-on

Answer (score 1):

To debug memory errors i suggest you run the program in valgrind

> valgrind --tool=memcheck program_name

and fix all the errors pointed by valgrind