# Array setup in constructor means failure later on

Tags: c++, arrays, constructor

I had an issue where my code segfaulted on attempting to use the size() function of a list.  On the advice of stackoverflow :-) I constructed a minimum case in which the segfault occurs (on the call inventory.size() below).  It is:

```
#include <list>

class Thing {};

class Player {
private:
  int xpCalcArray[99];
  std::list<Thing*> inventory;

public:
  Player();

  int addToInv(Thing& t); // return 1 on success, 0 on failure
};

Player::Player() {
  // set up XP calculation array
  for (int i=1; i<100; i++) {
    if (i<=10) {
      xpCalcArray[i] = i*100;
    }
    if (i>10 && i<=50) {
      xpCalcArray[i] = i*1000;
    }
    if (i>50 && i<=99) {
      xpCalcArray[i] = i*5000;
    }
  }
}

int Player::addToInv(Thing& t) {
  if (inventory.size() == 52) {
  return 0;
  } else {
      inventory.push_back(&t);
  }
  return 1;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  Thing t;
  Player pc;
  pc.addToInv(t);
  return 1;
}
```

I notice that when I remove the setting up of the array in the Player cosntructor, it works fine, so this looks to be the problem.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are accessing outside the bounds of your array. Doing so causes undefined behaviour and so there is no logical explanation for anything that occurs afterwards. The size of your array is 99 and so the last index is 98. Your `for` loop goes up to 99, however.

Either make your array size 100:

```
int xpCalcArray[100];
```

Or change your `for` condition to `i < 99`.

Answer (score 4):

You are accessing your array out of bounds, which results in **undefined behaviour**. The valid index range for this array

```
int xpCalcArray[99];
```

is 0 to 98. You are accessing index 99 here:

```
if (i>50 && i<=99) {
  xpCalcArray[i] = i*5000;
}
```

Your outer loop should be

```
for (int i=0; i<99; i++) { ... }
```

Note I start from 0, although it is an assumption that you actually want to access the first element.

Then your final condition can be simplified to

```
if (i>50) {
  xpCalcArray[i] = i*5000;
}
```

If you intended to use a size 100 array, then you need

```
int xpCalcArray[100];
```

then loop between `int i=0; i<100;`.

Comment: And obviously, one would use a *single constant* rather than hard-coding 50, 98, 99 and 100 about everywhere...

Answer (score 2):

You are overwriting your array of 99 `int`s by attempting to modify the 2nd→100th elements (rather than 1st→99th).

In your case, this happens to overwrite some memory within the `std::list<Thing*>` (which exists in memory directly after the array — *not always*, but evidently for you today) and thus, when you try to use the list, all hell breaks loose when its internal member data is no longer what it thought it was.

Answer (score 1):

You `xpCalcArray` is defined from 0 up to 98 (being 99 elements large).

Your loop goes from 0 up to 99, taking 100 steps.

The last loop cycle, writes `xpCalcArray` at location 99, which does not exist. This (indirectly) results in your segmentation fault as shown by [the answer of Lightness Races in Orbit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15133520/array-setup-in-constructor-means-failure-later-on/15133604#15133604).

So, increase the size of `xpCalcArray` by 1:

```
int xpCalcArray[100];
```

Comment: It _indirectly_ results in the segmentation fault. The only direct consequence here is invoking UB.

Comment: Yes you are right, your additional explanation of the cause is excellent!

Comment: Without knowing the intended logic of the code, increasing the size of the array is not necessarily the right solution. It could be, but we cannot be sure.

Comment: @juanchopanza well the OP is filling the array as if it had that size. Therefore, it seems to be required, and thus is increasing the array to the required size the right solution...

Comment: Actually, OP was only attempting to fill 99 places, just with the indices shifter by 1. I assumed it was more likely that they got the indexing wrong (i.e. they thought it was 1-based) rather than they got the array declaration syntax wrong (to think an array[99] has size 100 is rather strange). It seems I was wrong on that last assumption, and you were right!